# Android SQLiteException: "no such column" while duplicating column

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, ormlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have an sqlite database table with a primary ID and some columns. Now I wanted to add an additional column with the same value as the primary ID.

```
my_id integer primary key, ..., sort_order INTEGER
```

To do this, I excecute the following in onUpgrade() of my SQLite Helper

```
     if (oldVersion < 24) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + "my_table" + " ADD COLUMN " + "sort_order" + " INTEGER");
                database.execSQL("UPDATE my_table SET sort_order = my_id");
     }
```

**This worked fine for me and also for the beta users of this app.**

But now that I released this app to production, I got a large number of crash reports with

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: my_id(code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE my_table SET sort_order = my_id
```

Any idea what could be happening here? I rolled back to the previous version of my app and updated again, but I can not reproduce this crash on any of my devices!

**Update: Actual Code and Stacktrace**

Create Table:

```
DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists favrelations (dummyId integer primary key, _id integer, "
            + "room text not null, sort_order INTEGER);";
```

Upgrade:

```
if (oldVersion < 24) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + "favrelations" + " ADD COLUMN " + "sort_order" + " INTEGER");
            database.execSQL("UPDATE favrelations SET sort_order = dummyId");
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application de.me.MyApp.MyAppApp: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not construct instance of helper class class de.me.MyApp.DbAdapter.DataBaseAdapterManager
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3957)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not construct instance of helper class class de.me.MyApp.DbAdapter.DataBaseAdapterManager
at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.constructHelper(OpenHelperManager.java:222)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.loadHelper(OpenHelperManager.java:170)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.getHelper(OpenHelperManager.java:78)
at de.me.MyApp.DbAdapter.DataBaseAdapterManager.get(DataBaseAdapterManager.java:81)
at de.me.MyApp.MyAppApp.onCreate(MyAppApp.java:21)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3954)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.constructHelper(OpenHelperManager.java:220)
... 16 more
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: dummyId: , while compiling: UPDATE favrelations SET sort_order = dummyId
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:84)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1899)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1839)
at de.me.MyApp.DbAdapter.DataBaseAdapterManager.onUpgrade(DataBaseAdapterManager.java:285)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onUpgrade(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:240)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:170)
at de.me.MyApp.DbAdapter.DataBaseAdapterManager.<init>(DataBaseAdapterManager.java:88)
... 19 more
```

**Update 2**

I decided to just catch the error, drop the table and recreate it. This will lead to some loss of the users data, but at least they can use the app again. I would still be curious to know what causes this though.

Comment: is there any special proguard rules you're using when creating the release apk that could be messing with the code?

Comment: No, this app does have proguard enabled. And beta builds are also release builds, I just promoted the beta build to production. Its the same file

Comment: Do you have the sort_order column also in the `onCreate()` `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: Good point. But yes, it's also in onCreate()

Comment: If you are using ORMlite as your tags suggest, can you provide a smaple of your POJO for the `my_table` table

Comment: In hindsight that tag was probably not necessary: my database helper extends from OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper, but I am only using ORM for some newer tables, not for this one. There is no POJO for it.

Comment: On those devices, `dummyId` does not exist. This is probably an error from one of the earlier upgrades. (What's with those separate `dummyId` and `_id` anyway?)

Comment: dummyId was present in this table from the time this about was released, which was about 5 years ago. And a guy on an S6 has this problem, which was just released.

Comment: dummyId is the database id, _id is the id of this object in the cloud system I am synching this table with. And I wrote this code half a decade ago ;)